# calculate age in years months and days

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I got problem using `FROM_DAYS` function in mysql, i want to get age from my_table, here's my query;

```
select dob,CURRENT_DATE,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,dob)),'%y yr %c mth %e dy') AS age, 
DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,dob) days from my_table
```

result:

```
dob       || CURRENT_DATE || age              || days  ||
==========++==============++==================++=======++
1953-09-10|| 2013-09-12   || 60 yr 1 mth 3 dy || 21917 ||
2013-09-08|| 2013-09-12   || 00 yr 0 mth 0 dy ||     4 ||
```

when I tried `FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,m.tgllahir))` for 2nd row this is the result `0000-00-00`

and then I tried looking at [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and found this

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(730669);
        -> '2007-07-03'
```

but when I tried this is what I got;

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(730669);
        -> '2000-07-03'
```

I'm curious why `FROM_DAYS` function not working properly, but my main problem is how to find the age?

**EDIT**

after a discussion with  Barmar I know that I can't use FROM_DAYS to get accurate age, so I  tried to find different method

Comment: http://goharsahi.wordpress.com/2007/08/18/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-mysql/

Comment: @asharajay it's basically same query with mine

Comment: I think it's a mistake in the documentation. `730669/365.25 = 2000.46`.

Comment: `FROM_DAYS(n)` returns `0000-00-00` for all `n < 366`. The documentation says _Use FROM_DAYS() with caution on old dates. It is not intended for use with values that precede the advent of the Gregorian calendar (1582)_

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, my English aren't so good but I think it suppose to mean before year 1582, not value 1582. And by the way, on my example in first row, it's suppose to be 60yr 0mth 2dys? I tried with `FROM_DAYS(366)` and I get `0001-01-01` not `0001-00-01`? how is FROM_DAYS works actually?

Comment: `FROM_DAYS()` turns a number of days since year 0 into a date. So 366 is the first day of January in year 1, which is 0001-01-01 -- there is no month 00 in the calendar. I don't know why it doesn't work for the year 0, but that year is before the year 1582, so the documentation says not to use it for such old dates.

Comment: @Barmar ok now I got it, so any idea how can I get correct age?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FLOOR(( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(t.dob,'%Y%m%d'))/10000) AS years,
       FLOOR((1200 + DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(t.dob,'%m%d'))/100) %12 AS months,
       (SIGN(DAY(NOW()) - DAY(t.dob))+1)/2 * (DAY(NOW()) - DAY(t.dob)) +
      (SIGN(DAY(NOW()) - DAY(t.dob))+1)/2 * (DAY(NOW()) - DAY(t.dob)) +
      (SIGN(DAY(t.dob) - DAY(NOW()))+1)/2 * (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(t.dob + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY) - DAY(t.dob) + DAY(NOW())) AS days
 FROM tablename t
```

try this query

Answer (score 0):

This is a query I use to calculate age in years, months and days:

```
SELECT 
username
,dob
,DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS years
,PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m') , DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y%m') ) AS months
,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob) AS days
FROM users
```

Comment: Finally, the OP can carry on with their project

Answer (score 0):

To Use the FROM_DAYS() function and get the age of the person in the format you are looking for you must simply add a function to get the years months or days like so

```
CONCAT(
  YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),*DB LOCATION*))),' years,',
  MONTH(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),*DB LOCATION*))),' months,',
  DAY(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),*DB LOCATION*))),' days,',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using function.

This is the DDL of my function. This function is accurate and more precise.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_age $$
CREATE FUNCTION `f_age`(
        x_dob DATE
    )
    RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL

BEGIN
DECLARE x_result VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE y1, y2, m1, m2, d1, d2 INT;
DECLARE x1, x2 DATE;

  SET x_result = "";
  SET x1 = x_dob;
  SET x2 = CURDATE();

  IF (x1 < x2) THEN
    SET y1 = DATE_FORMAT(x1, '%Y');
    SET m1 = DATE_FORMAT(x1, '%c');
    SET d1 = DATE_FORMAT(x1, '%e');

    SET y2 = DATE_FORMAT(x2, '%Y');
    SET m2 = DATE_FORMAT(x2, '%c');
    SET d2 = DATE_FORMAT(x2, '%e');

    IF (d1 > d2) THEN
        SET m2 = m2 - 1;

        IF (m2 = 0) THEN
            SET y2 = y2 - 1;
            SET m2 = 12;
        END IF;

        SET d2 = d2 + DAY(LAST_DAY(CONCAT_WS("-", y2, m2, d2)));
    END IF;

    IF (m1 > m2) THEN
        SET y2 = y2 - 1;
        SET m2 = m2 + 12;
    END IF;

    IF (y2 > y1) THEN
        SET x_result = CONCAT((y2 - y1), ' yr ');
    END IF;

    IF ((y2 > y1) OR (m2 > m1)) THEN
        SET x_result = CONCAT(x_result, CONCAT((m2 - m1), ' mth '));
    END IF;

    IF ((y2 > y1) OR (m2 > m1) OR (d2 > d1)) THEN
        SET x_result = CONCAT(x_result, CONCAT((d2 - d1), ' dy'));
    END IF;
  ELSE
    SET x_result = "Error. Date of birth is today or more than today";
  END IF;

  RETURN x_result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Than, here is code to use the function:

```
SELECT f_age(dob) FROM table;
```

It also handle leap year accurately

Comment: Where is this "more precise" and why do you think leap years are not taken into account in the other answers?

Comment: Hi @nico, let's try using the **Mark's** answer using Now() = 2018-01-25 and dob = 2017-01-01, the result is 1 yr 1 mt **24** dy (it's true), but when we change dob = 2016-01-01 the result will be 1 yr 1 mt **25** dy (it's not true because 2016 is leap year). When using my function, the result it's 1 yr 1 mt 24 dy and 2 yr 1 mt 24 dy (the day is accurate)

Comment: If in both cases NOW() = xx-01-01 and dob = xx-01-01, the result should never contain any months or days...

Comment: Mine? yes i think the age is zero.. so i skip the calculation when the NOW = dob, what's your opinion?

Comment: That's a completely unneccessary addition to your algorithm. Don't make it more complicated as it needs to be

Comment: Do you have try the all method from the answers? which one you choose to answer the main question (to get age in format .. yr .. mth .. dy)?