# MySQL Calculate age by year month and day

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display data of patients age.

```
mysql> select nama,gender,dob,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,now()) as age from sampelaja;
+------------------+--------+------------+------+
| nama             | gender | dob        | age  |
+------------------+--------+------------+------+
| Rizkiyandi       |      1 | 2010-05-21 |    4 |
| Siti Khodijah    |      0 | 1980-03-15 |   34 |
| Aisyah Az-zahra  |      0 | 1986-08-17 |   28 |
| Paritem          |      0 | 2005-12-13 |    8 |
| Ngadimin         |      1 | 2014-08-28 |    0 |
+------------------+--------+------------+------+

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here there is a problem when there is a 4-day-old baby who is regarded as the age of 0 year
**I want a result like this**

```
+------------------+--------+------------+------+-------+------+
| nama             | gender | dob        | year | month | day  |
+------------------+--------+------------+------+-------+------+
| Rizkiyandi       |      1 | 2010-05-21 |    4 |     3 |   13 |
| Siti Khodijah    |      0 | 1980-03-15 |   34 |     5 |   18 |
| Aisyah Az-zahra  |      0 | 1986-08-17 |   28 |     0 |   16 |
| Paritem          |      0 | 2005-12-13 |    8 |     8 |   20 |
| Ngadimin         |      1 | 2014-08-28 |    0 |     0 |    6 |
+------------------+--------+------------+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Check this it might help you http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,378024,378912

Comment: you can get TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY) and then div by 365 for year and remainder greator than 30 then div by 30 (for average number of months) and the remainder will be days. or a combination of TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR)   and then MONTH AND DAY and deduct the months by the value of YEAR * 12 and DAY by YEAR * 365 AND MONTH * 30

Comment: or see here for some other ways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756546/calculate-age-in-years-months-and-days

Comment: if the result is such that ,how I want to display the data of patients aged less than 30 days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use modulo to determine count of months and days:

```
SELECT
      nama
    , gender
    , dob
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dob, now() ) as _year
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, dob, now() ) % 12 as _month
    , FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, dob, now() ) % 30.4375 ) as _day
FROM 
    sampelaja
```

The result is:

```
+-----------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+------+
| nama            | gender | dob        | _year | _month | _day |
+-----------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+------+
| Rizkiyandi      |      1 | 2010-05-21 |     4 |      3 |   13 |
| Siti Khodijah   |      0 | 1980-03-15 |    34 |      5 |   19 |
| Aisyah Az-zahra |      0 | 1986-08-17 |    28 |      0 |   17 |
| Paritem         |      0 | 2005-12-13 |     8 |      8 |   20 |
| Ngadimin        |      1 | 2014-08-28 |     0 |      0 |    6 |
+-----------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+------+
```

Days are calculated between birthday date from previous month till today.

Number `30.4375` I calculated using this formula: [DAYS IN YEAR]/12, where [DAYS IN YEAR] = 365.25

Comment: thank you bro. whether this query can be used as a table view? because I want to make a criterion if a patient is older than 10 days

Comment: Yes, you can add `WHERE` clause to filter records less than 10 years: `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dob, now() ) < 10`. Or you can create `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: A test case is that

dob='2018-02-15 00:00:00', 
now='2018-04-17 00:00:00',

your query return 0 year 2 month 0 day, 

which is not correct, can you help me regarding this thing @Nicolai

Comment: @MajbahHabib, there are 61 day between your dates. Because I used approximations (1 month is 30.4375 days), the query returns `0.1250` days. Function `FLOOR` rounds this value to zero. You may prefer to count this partial day as a full day. To make this use function `CEIL` instead of `FLOOR`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to calculate this using the query below. The query calculates the exact years, months and days.

This information can also be found on the mysql date calculations page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html

```
SELECT 
    nama, 
    gender, 
    dob,

    /* Select the number of years */
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        YEAR,
        dob,
        CURDATE()
    ) AS years,

    /* Select the number of months by adding the number of years to the 'dob' date field */
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        MONTH, 
        DATE_ADD(
            dob ,
            INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) YEAR
        ),
        CURDATE()
    ) AS months,

    /* Select the number of days by adding the number of years and number of months to the 'dob' field */
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
        DAY,
        DATE_ADD(
            DATE_ADD(
                dob ,
                INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()
            ) YEAR),
            INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                MONTH, 
                DATE_ADD(
                    dob ,
                    INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,CURDATE()) YEAR
                ),
                CURDATE()
            ) MONTH
        ),
        CURDATE()
    ) AS days
FROM
    sampelaja
```

Comment: thank you bro.
you answer correctly. but too long. whether it can be used as a table view?I want to select an answer both but could not, have to choose one suitable answer:-(

Answer (score 3):

### Problems in the accepted answer

The method in accepted answer is good, but leap years goof it up on birthdays. Here is some test cases:

```
create table sample (dob datetime,now datetime);
insert into sample (dob,now)values
('2012-02-29', '2013-02-28'),
('2012-02-29', '2016-02-28'),
('2012-02-29', '2016-03-31'),
('2012-01-30', '2016-02-29'),
('2012-01-30', '2016-03-01'),
('2011-12-30', '2016-02-29');

SELECT
      date_format(dob,'%Y-%m-%d')
    , date_format(now,'%Y-%m-%d')
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dob, now ) as _year
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, dob, now ) % 12 as _month
    , FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, dob, now ) % 30.4375 ) as _day
 FROM sample

       DOB         NOW YEAR     MONTH  DAY
2012-02-29  2013-02-28    0     11      30  -- 28 days would be better
2012-02-29  2016-02-28    3     11      29  -- 28 days would be better
2012-02-29  2016-03-31    4      1       0  -- 2 days would be better
2012-01-30  2016-02-29    4      0      30  
2012-01-30  2016-03-01    4      1       0  -- 2 days should be right
2011-12-30  2016-02-29    4      1       0  -- The right answer should be 4 years 1 months 30 days
```

### Here's my approach, use arithmetic only

```
select
       DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%Y-%m-%d'),
       DATE_FORMAT(now,'%Y-%m-%d'),
       FLOOR(( DATE_FORMAT(now,'%Y%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%Y%m%d'))/10000),
       FLOOR((1200 + DATE_FORMAT(now,'%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m%d'))/100) %12,
      (sign(day(now) - day(dob))+1)/2 * (day(now) - day(dob)) + 
      (sign(day(dob) - day(now))+1)/2 * (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(dob + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                                         - day(dob) + day(now))
       -- Explain: if the days of now is bigger than the days of birth, then diff the two days
       --          else add the days of now and the distance from the date of birth to the end of the birth month 
from sample
```

### Test cases and results:

```
       DOB         NOW  YEARS   MONTHS  DAYS
2012-02-29  2013-02-28     0    11      28
2012-02-29  2016-02-28     3    11      28
2012-02-29  2016-03-31     4     1       2
2012-01-30  2016-02-29     4     0      30
2012-01-30  2016-03-01     4     1       2
2011-12-30  2016-02-29     4     1      30
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a glitch to the days column in Jaugar Chang's answer when the dates have the same day. I think the following corrects for this:

```
(SELECT CASE sign(day(now)-day(dob)) 
  WHEN 0 THEN 0 
  WHEN 1 THEN day(now)-day(dob)
  ELSE (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(dob + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 DAY)-day(dob)+day(now)) END)
  as days
```

For completeness the amended version of Jaugar's answer would follow:

```
SELECT 
FLOOR(( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d') - DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%Y%m%d'))/10000) as year,
FLOOR((1200 + DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d')-DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m%d'))/100) %12 as month,
CASE sign(day(NOW())-day(dob))
  WHEN 0 THEN 0
  WHEN 1 THEN day(NOW())-day(dob)
  ELSE (DAY(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(dob + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 DAY)-day(dob)+day(NOW())) END as day
FROM sampelaja
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is a query I use to calculate age in years, months and days

```
SELECT nama, gender, dob
,DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS years
,PERIOD_DIFF( DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m') , DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y%m') ) AS months
,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob) AS days
FROM sampelaja
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function is copied from various resources and merged into one.
This will return complete date in terms of years, months and days.
Also it can be modified to display either one.
Also the current_time is taken as input so that we can calculate age relative to any other date also.

```
DROP function IF EXISTS `calculate_age`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `calculate_age`(`dob` DATE,  `current_time` DATETIME) 
RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
DECLARE years varchar(10);
DECLARE months varchar(9);
DECLARE days varchar(7);
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(current_time, dob)/365) INTO years;
SELECT FLOOR((DATEDIFF(current_time,dob)/365 - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(current_time,dob)/365))* 12) INTO months;
SELECT CEILING((((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob)/365 
- FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob)/365))* 12) - FLOOR((DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob)/365 - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dob)/365))* 12))* 30) into days;
RETURN CONCAT_WS
            ( ', '
        , CASE WHEN years = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(years,'y') END
        , CASE WHEN months = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(months, 'm') END
        , CASE WHEN days = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(days, 'days') END
        );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(
  cast(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, str_to_date('14/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y'), str_to_date('14/05/2019','%d/%m/%Y')) AS char),' years ',
    cast(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, str_to_date('14/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y'), str_to_date('14/05/2019','%d/%m/%Y')), 12) as char), ' months ',
  cast(DATEDIFF(str_to_date('14/05/2019','%d/%m/%Y'),
  DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(str_to_date('14/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, str_to_date('14/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y'),str_to_date('14/05/2019','%d/%m/%Y'))
  YEAR),
  INTERVAL MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, str_to_date('14/08/2018','%d/%m/%Y'),str_to_date('14/05/2019','%d/%m/%Y')),12) MONTH)) AS char),' days') as Age
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT
      nama
    , gender
    , dob
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dob, now() ) as _year
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, dob, now() ) % 12 as _month
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, now()), dob), now()) as _day
FROM 
    sampelaja
```

When you divide with 30.4375 for exact days, you may not get right answer. So you can calculate exact months upto dob and subtract that date from today's date to get the exact days. You can check/verify the same using online age calculator here https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dt.dt, NOW()) AS y,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, dt.dt, NOW())%12  AS m,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF ( day, 
        DATE_ADD( adddate(curdate(), day( dt.dt) - day(curdate())), interval 
        -(day( dt.dt)>day(curdate())) month), 
        curdate()) as days
FROM (select date('1975-08-07') as dt ) as dt;
```